# Java Spring - How to execute GraphQL queries under Rest URI?

Tags: java, spring, rest, graphql

I have an Rest URI like `/books`, and in that URI it will execute any kind of GraphQL queries related to books only, and the queries depend on the request param like `?id`, `?name`, etc...

I'm trying to implement this idea using Spring framework but got the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception >[Circular view path [books]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/books] >again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified >view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
>
> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [books]: would dispatch back to the >current handler URL [/books] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the >result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Is this posible to implement this kind of execution? If it is, what did I do wrong?

Here is the code for the Controller:

```
package com.example.graphqlserver;

import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.SchemaMapping;
// import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public Book getBook(@RequestParam(name = "id", defaultValue = "") String id) {
        return this.bookById(id);
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
        return Book.getById(id);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Author author(Book book) {
        return Author.getById(book.authorId());
    }
}
```

Code for the classes:

Book:

```
package com.example.graphqlserver;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public record Book(String id, String name, int pageCount, String authorId) {

    private static List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("book-1", "Effective Java", 416, "author-1"),
            new Book("book-2", "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", 208, "author-2"),
            new Book("book-3", "Down Under", 436, "author-3"));

    public static Book getById(String id) {
        return books.stream()
                .filter(book -> book.id().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Author:

```
package com.example.graphqlserver;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public record Author(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {

    private static List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(
            new Author("author-1", "Joshua", "Bloch"),
            new Author("author-2", "Douglas", "Adams"),
            new Author("author-3", "Bill", "Bryson"));

    public static Author getById(String id) {
        return authors.stream()
                .filter(author -> author.id().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
    bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
    id: ID
    name: String
    pageCount: Int
    author: Author
}

type Author {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding both `@RestController` and `@Controller` to the Controller class and it returned "kind of" expected result:

`localhost:8080/books?id=book-1`

```
{
  "id": "book-1",
  "name": "Effective Java",
  "pageCount": 416,
  "authorId": "author-1"
}
```

Updated code:

```
package com.example.graphqlserver;

import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.SchemaMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping("/books")
    public Book getBook(@RequestParam(name = "id", defaultValue = "") String id) {
        return this.bookById(id);
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
        return Book.getById(id);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Author author(Book book) {
        return Author.getById(book.authorId());
    }
}
```